# Calculate the size of data being received in PHP /Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Usingg the Ajax request i get content which is displayed on the web page.

The content can be only strings / string + html content / string + images.

I need to calculate the total size of the content and if it exceeds 200Kb, I do not have to show it on the HTML page.

How do i calculate the size of the content in either jQuery/Angualarjs/Javascript/PHP?

Comment: check whether the resource send the Content-Length header

Comment: Nope. no Content-Length header in the response header.

Comment: Are all the images local to the server or can also be external?

Comment: Well the image can be either. How would it effect anyway ?

Answer (score 1):

Modify your PHP backend:

```
ob_start();
// all content generated here ...
$output = ob_get_clean();
if ( strlen($output) > (200*1024) ) {
    //return error to frontend
} else {
    echo $output;
}
```

Comment: I even have image src in the content

Comment: so, you need ( strlen($html) + filesize( $physical_path_to_image1 ) +.. + filesize($physical_path_to_imageN) ) <= 200kb ? Then it be better to sum filesizes between ob_start() and(ob_get_clean()): if result exceeds, ob_clean() instantly and send error

Comment: so i actually ended up using ob_get_length(). Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
ob_start();
$output = ob_get_length();
```

or if you have to set the content-length param then add the following to above code:

```
header("Content-Length: $output");
```